# Select start frame and end frame in video using OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv, video

This below code will assign the current frame number to a variable:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('my_video.wmv');
start = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
```

This is what I need, but I am only able to get the first frame in the video this way `0.0`.

Is there any way to watch the video and use a keyboard shortcut to select the `start` frame and the `end` frame?

For example, I can create the video clip with the desired in-point and out-point i.e. 400 to 700. But, this is done manually in the below code.

```
cv2.namedWindow('mywindow')
cv2.createTrackbar( 'start', 'mywindow', 400, length, onChange )
cv2.createTrackbar( 'end'  , 'mywindow', 700, length, onChange )
```

*Thus, my question is: how can I get these two numbers i.e. 400 & 700 using the keyboard shortcuts.*

Comment: Have you looked into (repeatedly) calling [`cv2.waitKey()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey)?  [**This example**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file) uses it on every frame to check for the 'q' key.  Combining waitKey with [`setTrackbarPos`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar#settrackbarpos) seems reasonable.

Comment: @jedwards No, I haven't looked into that yet. I am pretty new to OpenCV, I just started learning it a couple of weeks ago. Can you please let me know more about how the (repeatedly) calling cv2.waitKey() works?

Comment: @jedwards Thanks for the additional links in your comment. I just noticed your edit. I am looking at the links now.

Comment: Check out the example I linked in the comment.  The `waitKey()` function is called with a low timeout value (1 in their case), so it doesn't block the video playback if a key is not pressed.  If you want to change the trackbar values using code, in response to keyboard events, you could combine `waitKey` (to detect key presses and determine what sliders should update and how) and `setTrackbarPos` to apply the changes.

Comment: @jedwards Thanks. I see what you mean. It sounds interesting, I think this might do the trick. I will play around with it and try to make this work. I will let you know how it turns out. Thanks again.

Comment: @jedwards In principle, it works. But, at this point, I can only get the start frame, not the end frame. So, I am still trying to figure out how to get more than one frame. But, it's a great idea.

Comment: Are you trying to *get* the start/end frames (i.e. get the current value of the sliders) or *set* the start/end frames (i.e. control the value of the sliders via keyboard events)?  If it's the latter, there's also [`getTrackbarPos()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar#gettrackbarpos)

Comment: @jedwards I am trying to get the start/end frames, store them and later use them to select and play those clips. So, from the video, I need to select many start/end frames, then use them later to play the selected clips only.

Comment: Then you may look into `getTrackbarPos` instead (or in addition), sorry for misunderstanding.  Just make sure you specify *which* trackbar you're interested in via the first argument.

Comment: @jedwards I am sorry, the problem is in my communication. As I mentioned, I am new to OpenCV. What I meant was that I need the frame number, not the actual image. Just the number so I can play the video between the 2 frame numbers i.e. `cv2.createTrackbar( 'start', 'mywindow', 400, length, onChange )
cv2.createTrackbar( 'end'  , 'mywindow', 700, length, onChange )`

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to get the current frame number other than to initialize a counter to 0 and increment it manually each time you call `cam.read()`.  I'm also not sure the best way to play only a segment of a video back other than to read and throw away `start` number of frames, read and continue incrementing the counter, and stop reading once you've reached `stop` frames.  At least that's what I did.  There may be a better way.

Comment: @jedwards Thanks so much for your help. I still think that your idea about `cv2.waitKey(1)` will actually work. I have to figure out how to get the frame number multiple times in the `if` statement. If I can do that, I think I can play the selected video segment with `cv2.createTrackbar`. I am still trying...

Comment: @jedwards I kept trying the `cv2.waitKey()` idea and I made it work. Basically, I can get the video frame start/end numbers and I can play the video clip between those frames. The code doesn't look pretty, it's kind of a hack... but it works as expected. Thanks again for this great idea!